# When try to use TypeScript instead of JavaScript get an error: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

We have Vue.js 2.6 app when we use JavaScript, but there's some code written in TypeScript. I'm not much in TypeScript and try to rewrite the code that uses Axios. It looks as following:

**1) Caller:**

```
try {
  const params = {
    id: 1,
    inn: 2,
    withReferences: true,
  };
  const result = await gpbApi.leadService.getPartnerReferences(params);
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error = ', error);
}
```

**2) Call:**

```
async getPartnerReferences(params: any) {
  if (!params) return;
  const { data } = await axios.get(`${path}/GroupAccountService/PartnerReferences`, params, { 
    withCredentials: true
  });
  return data.data;
}
```

Comment: Well. `axios.get` has [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) which says it does take 2 arguments, one of which is optional, and you *are* passing 3. So the error message is correct. The use of the `params` variable appears to be nonsense. (The problem isn't new in TypeScript, you still have the problem in JavaScript, it's just that TypeScript *tells* you about it … this is why I'm a TypeScript fan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) points out in the comments, the [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) has one required parameter (url) and one optional parameter (config). Your code passes three parameters, so the error is accurate, and the three-parameter `get` call wasn't doing what you were expecting in either JS or TS.

However, the `config` parameter accepts a key called `params`, which is likely where your `params` were intended to go. You can use [Javascript shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions) to just use the name `params` rather than `params: params`. This means your fix is just to move the `params` to the *inside* of the object initializer (curly braces).

If this code worked before, it's possible that `params` was once in the object initializer on the same line as the URL but was mistakenly moved outside of it.

```
async getPartnerReferences(params: any) {
  if (!params) return;
  const { data } = await axios.get(`your.url`, {
    params, // this is now a part of the config object
    withCredentials: true
  });
  return data.data;
}
```